# How to solve eclipse cross-compilation c/c++ error. Symbol could not be resolved issue

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, cross-compiling

I'm trying to make changes and compile open source 3d printers firmware in eclipse. Added all the project related to firmware but it showing symbol could not be resolved error. The cause of error is IDE cannot find the symbols. How can I solve this. It's compiling properly and also working on board.[image]

Comment: Why both C and C++ ? Your problem concerns `size_t` and `uint32_t`etc in your editor ? or your problem occurs at compile time ? or at link time ?

Comment: You need to point to the cross compilation include path in the Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols, which should allow it to find the relevant symbols for parsing.

Comment: Please do not post images.  Rather copy/paste the code into your question as text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not showing a problem in the actual code and the posted code is an image rather than text, so we cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: @user3629249 this question is related to IDE so I took snap. Otherwise it would show only code. I never used IDE so have little trouble using that. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in indexer of the eclipse used active configuration settings and it solved all the Indexer error. Thanks for the help guys.